# find custom workflow template in feature receiver in sharepoint 2013

Tags: workflow, custom, template

Task is to bind a workflow to a content type in feature activated event.
Based on http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-associate-workflow-to-content-type-in-a-feature#.VDfDzXlxlaR
we've got to find the already deployed custom workflow. But looking at the **WorkflowTemplates collection of the web: there are only the 2 Standard** (approver, 3-state) **in**.
**So where to find the custom workflow template**?

Used code in the feature receiver

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
 using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site)
 {
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
    try
    {
      //test
      SPWeb myWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
      foreach (SPWorkflowTemplate tmp in myWeb.WorkflowTemplates)
      {
        //...;
      }
      //normally
      SPWorkflowTemplate wfTempl = web.WorkflowTemplates.GetTemplateByName("myworkflow", currentCulture)
```

And, yes! The workflow is really deployed coz if we try to add it to a library we can see it, assign it and us it...!?

Comment: Firstly not a good practice to use SPContext.Current.Site in feature receivers and also whenever you use SPContext.Current.Site do not dispose that object (don't add it inside using).  Are you activating this feature in the root web?

Comment: i tried both. Have a look at the first line after //test. There is the common practice (using the parent property of the feature). But the result is the same. I always got only the two Standard workflow templates.

Comment: So are you getting any error while fetching the workflow template?

Comment: no error; it just returns null using GetTemplateByName. If you debug the Content of WorkflowTemplates collection you just find the common Standard Workflows.

Comment: So when are you deploying your workflow? Check if workflow is deployed before you run this code? Or you can check while activating the feature from UI

Comment: as a said in the thread: "The workflow is really deployed: if we try to add it to a library we can see it, assign it and us it"

Comment: I think the main problem here is that the feature event receiver looking at the Workflows traces the workflows on site collection level whereas the workflow feature is a site feature